# Q: [Sharepoint Online] People picker shows no matches

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker

We have a Sharepoint Online site which has a list with a people picker field.

One specific user can not find anyone by typing a name in the people picker field. Every time he gets the message "No results".

[image]

When he edits a list item that already has values in the people picker field, he sees how many people were selected in the field but not who those people are. Also the message "We couldn't find an exact match".

[image]

When I add/edit a list item on the site, I can select the people just fine. And the person who is experiencing the issues has the exact same rights as me.

And idea what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd raise that as a support ticket from the Office Portal.
Go to [Portal.Office.com](https://portal.office.com) and select Support -> New service request. You can search for a solution and then if you can't see anything in the answers provided, click 'Contact Us' to get contact options for someone to call you, or e-mail you.